# How do I restore the default applets to Gnome's notification area?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-9.10, notifications, applet

I have a fresh install of Karmic Koala. In a botched attempt at trying to change my default window manager, I somehow removed at least three applets from the notification area: network manager (`nm-applet`), volume control (`gnome-volume-control-applet`), and the battery meter (???). Now if I logout and back in, these applets don't run, but I can start them from the command line.

Because it's a fresh install, I completely removed my luser account and home directory. After recreating my account, I was frustrated to find that the applets are still missing and no obvious way to add them back.

How can I restore the default configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The panel configuration is stored in gconf.  Try these commands:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Hat-tip http://www.watchingthenet.com/restore-panels-in-ubuntu-back-to-their-default-settings.html

Comment: No dice. I even tried logging out and back in, but I still got the mostly empty notification area.